# matching and filling in blanks of data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have data with double entries, that looks like this:

```
+-----+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| id  | first |   last    | birthyear | father |
+-----+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| a12 | linda | john      | 1991      | NA     |
| 3n8 | max   | well      | 1915      | NA     |
| 15z | linda | NA        | 1991      | dan    |
| 1y9 | pam   | degeneres | 1855      | NA     |
| 84z | NA    | degeneres | 1950      | hank   |
| 9i5 | max   | well      | NA        | mike   |
+-----+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

There are multiple entries for a single person, but each entry has unique data that needs to be preserved. I want to merge these entries, keeping all information. Only the "id" column does not have to match, i want to keep the first "id" entry in the list as the final "id". So my final dataframe would look like this:

```
+-----+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| id  | first |   last    | birthyear | father |
+-----+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| a12 | linda | john      | 1991      | dan    |
| 3n8 | max   | well      | 1915      | mike   |
| 1y9 | pam   | degeneres | 1855      | NA     |
| 84z | NA    | degeneres | 1950      | hank   |
+-----+-------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

In this example, there are two entries with last name "degeneres" who did not get merged because the birthyear does not match. The entries where there were only matching entries (aside from NAs) did get merged.

So far, the farthest i got is generating a list ordered by matching first names:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("a12", "3n8", "15z", "1y9", "84z", "9i5"), first = c("linda", "max", "linda", "pam", NA, "max"), last = c("john", "well", NA, "degeneres", "degeneres", "well"), birthyear = c("1991", "1915", "1991", "1855", "1950", NA), father = c(NA, NA, "dan", NA, "hank", "mike"), stringsAsFactors = F)

name_list <- list()
i <- 1
for(n in df$first) {
  name_list[[i]] <- df[df$first == n,]
  i <<- i + 1
}
```

I also tried to apply merge in a meaningful way, but that does not give me the desired results:

```
merge(x = df, y = df, by = c("first", "last", "birthyear", "father"))

+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+------+------+
|   first |   last    | birthyear | father | id.x | id.y |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+------+------+
| linda   | john      | 1991      | <NA>   | a12  | a12  |
| linda   | NA        | 1991      | dan    | 15z  | 15z  |
| max     | well      | 1915      | NA     | 3n8  | 3n8  |
| max     | well      | NA        | mike   | 9i5  | 9i5  |
| NA      | degeneres | 1950      | hank   | 84z  | 84z  |
| pam     | degeneres | 1855      | NA     | 1y9  | 1y9  |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+------+------+
```

how could i best proceed?

EDIT:

Thanks for the responses so far! Just to be clear: I don't want to be conservative in determining which row describes a unique person. For example, this input:

```
+-----+-------+------+-----------+--------+
| id  | first | last | birthyear | father |
+-----+-------+------+-----------+--------+
| 9i5 | max   | well | NA        | mike   |
| 9i6 | dan   | well | NA        | mike   |
| 9i7 | NA    | well | NA        | NA     |
+-----+-------+------+-----------+--------+
```

needs to give this output:

```
+-----+-------+------+-----------+--------+
| id  | first | last | birthyear | father |
+-----+-------+------+-----------+--------+
| 9i5 | max   | well | NA        | mike   |
| 9i6 | dan   | well | NA        | mike   |
+-----+-------+------+-----------+--------+
```

EDIT2:

So i've used Adam's script on my data set. It works great, there is only a hiccup because of exactly the problem that Salix predicted/found. I have a row with very little data about my woman named Linda. Turns out, there are two Linda's that are definitely unique, and a third entry named Linda with no further information.

The script is now trying to match the unknown Linda to both of the other two unique Linda's. I've traced the issue down to a collision in the merge_id object. For my data set, it looks like this:

```
+------+------+
| V1   | V2   |
+------+------+
|  188 |  916 |
|  188 | 1048 |
|  752 | 1048 |
|  916 | 1048 |
| 1048 | 1058 |
+------+------+
```

As you can see, person 1048 matches with people who do not match with eachother. So for example 188 - 916 - 1048 could all be the same person, because 188 matches 916, 188 matches 1048 and 916 matches 1048. All fine.

But then person 752 also matches with 1048, but does not match with 188 or 916. Ergo, 1048 does not have enough information and needs to be deleted.

I'm trying to come up with a function that detects this collision and deletes 1048 from the dataset.

Comment: Are you just trying to fill in NAs where you can?

Comment: yes. unless there is conflicting data, then i want to treat each entry as separate.

Comment: Could you provide an example of conflicting data?

Comment: I gave one in the post, there are two entries with last name "degeneres", but one has birthyear 1950 and the other has birthyear 1855. In the desired output, they remain separate entries.

Comment: I guess i should not call it "conflicting" data. They just don't match.

Comment: This is an interesting problem and might be trickier than it looks. Is there a threshold for amount of overlap you want to use? I could imagine a "greedy" implementation leading to excessive matches; e.g. if you had a row with "linda" and "1991" does that mean all lindas with missing years should be assigned to 1991, even though only one with a year was found?

Comment: ...and what if you also have a row with only "linda" and "1980"? Can you use neither since there isn't enough to uniquely connect either one to other rows with "linda" and missing years?

Comment: Hi Jon! For my specific case I would need a "greedy" implementation. My motivation is that I am trying to compile a list of unique people out of a set of loose data that spans several years and contains each person multiple times. I want to keep ONLY uniquely identifiable people, so if some people get lost due to lack of information that is not a problem. I'm working on a research project and I don't want to use bad or incomplete data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how efficient this is, but this seems to be working. I am using 3 custom functions.

This would be easy to adapt to have it not match if there are two many NA's in a row and other cases such as that. The main trick is in `f_compare()` to build two dataframes representing each row combination to compare against rather than looping.

### Functions:

**f_compare()**

Compare each row to itself. We use `combn()` to develop all the unique row combinations. This function will return a matrix with two columns. These two columns specify row numbers which are "duplicates" - defined as ignoring the first column and by counting `NA` as a match.

Edit: Extended the logic to force a minimum number of fields to actually match by value rather than from an `NA` wildcard. We require the number of `TRUE` match values in the row plus the number of `NA` values in the row to equal the total number of fields.

Edit2: Added a check to see if a record is "bad". If there are matched pairs (a, b) and (c, b), it checks to see if (a, c) or (c, a) is a pair as well. If not, then the offending record c is dropped from the database. Again, this could fairly easily be adapted to flag rather than drop the row.

```
f_compare <- function(dat, .min_match = 1, .exclude_cols = c(1)) {
  
  # grid of unique row id combinations
  dat_rows <- t(combn(seq_len(nrow(dat)), 2))
  
  # grid of all row id combinations (e.g., (1, 2) and (2, 1))
  dat_rows_all <- expand.grid(seq_len(nrow(dat)), seq_len(nrow(dat)))
  dat_rows_all <- dat_rows_all[dat_rows_all[,1] != dat_rows_all[,2], ]
  
  # function to find record matches based on a grid specification
  f_match <- function(dat, dat_rows, .min_match, .exclude_cols) {
    
    compare <- dat[dat_rows[, 1], -.exclude_cols] == dat[dat_rows[, 2], -.exclude_cols]
    
    row_true <- rowSums(compare, na.rm = TRUE)
    row_na <- rowSums(is.na(compare))
    
    which_rows <- which((row_true >= .min_match) & (row_true + row_na == ncol(compare)))
    rbind(dat_rows[which_rows,])
    
  }
  
  # matches for each grid
  match_rows <- f_match(dat, dat_rows, .min_match, .exclude_cols)
  match_rows_all <- f_match(dat, dat_rows_all, .min_match, .exclude_cols)
  
  # function to determine if it is a "bad" record
  f_bad <- function(check_index, id_comb, id_all) {
    
    if (length(id_comb[id_comb[,2] == check_index, 1]) > 1) {
      trans_rows <- t(combn(id_comb[id_comb[,2] == check_index, 1], 2))
    
      compare_trans <- id_all[rep(seq_len(nrow(id_all)), times = nrow(trans_rows)),] == trans_rows[rep(seq_len(nrow(trans_rows)), each = nrow(id_all)),]
    
      return(!any(rowSums(compare_trans) == ncol(compare_trans)))
    } else {
      return(FALSE)
    }
  }
  
  # check all rows with a potential match to see if it is "bad"
  check_ids <- unique(match_rows[,2])
  
  if (length(check_ids) > 0) {
    bad_ids <- check_ids[sapply(check_ids, f_bad, match_rows, match_rows_all)]
  } else {
    bad_ids = check_ids
  }
  
  list(id = rbind(match_rows[!(match_rows[,2] %in% bad_ids), ]), bad_id = bad_ids)

}
```

**f_merge()**

Given two vectors, `x` and `y`, fill in `NA` slots in each with values from the other.

```
f_merge <- function(id, dat) {
  x <- dat[id[1],]
  y <- dat[id[2],]
  
  y[is.na(y)] <- x[is.na(y)]
  x[is.na(x)] <- y[is.na(x)]
  
  x
}
```

**merge_records()**

Recursively work through the data set until there are no more duplicates left to merge. There is some case logic in here to account for things like R converting a single row matrix to a vector and when to exit the recursion.

Edit2: Modified the merge to drop "bad" records.

```
merge_records <- function(dat) {
  merge_id <- f_compare(dat)
  
  # drop bad rows
  if (length(merge_id$bad_id) > 0) {
    dat <- dat[-merge_id$bad_id,]
  }
  
  dat2 <- do.call("rbind", apply(merge_id$id, 1, f_merge, dat = dat))
  dat2 <- rbind(dat2, dat[which(!(seq_len(nrow(dat)) %in% c(merge_id$id))), ])
  
  if (nrow(dat2) > 1) {
    dat2 <- dat2[which(!(duplicated(dat2))),]
    
    if (nrow(f_compare(dat2)$id) > 0) merge_records(dat2) else return(dat2)
  } else {
    dat2
  }
  
}
```

### End Result:

```
merge_records(df)
```

```
    id first      last birthyear father
1  a12 linda      john      1991    dan
21 3n8   max      well      1915   mike
5  1y9   pam degeneres      1855   <NA>
6  84z  <NA> degeneres      1950   hank
```

Comment: to test my thing I added some more entries to have more variety on where the NAs were, have 2 persons with the same last name, and I tried this on that df and it gives weird results :/

Comment: the df for ref : df <- data.frame(
  id = c("d33","d34","a11", "a12", "3n8", "15z", "ba4", "1y9", "84z", "9i5"), 
  first = c("linda","linda",NA, "linda", "max", "linda", "max", "pam", NA, "max"), 
  last = c("well","well","john", "john", "well", NA, NA, "degeneres", "degeneres", "well"), 
  birthyear = c("1992","1991","1991", "1991", "1915", "1991", NA, "1855", "1950", NA), 
  father = c("robert","robert",NA, NA, NA, "dan", NA, NA, "hank", "mike"), 
  stringsAsFactors = T)

Comment: don't even know if op checked the answers, but did you try yours with more than 1 .min_match? it duplicates ids. Also, you forgot to make the new args passable from the main one. But, yeah, playing around with your script, the only way I found to not duplicate ids (and sometimes have weird results) was to use f_merge() with only the first row of merge_id, remove duplicates and then recheck merge_id with new data, etc, until merge_id had no rows.

Comment: hey guys, sorry for the slow reply, i haven't been around much in the weekend. i'm testing both of your scripts now, they look promising! thanks for the effort :)

Comment: Hey Adam, so i've run your script and it is definitely the most promising one so far! My dataset went from 1243 rows to 1227 rows. That may not seem like much, but the reduction combined with the knowledge that none of these people have the same info is exactly what i'm looking for! Thank you so much for your work.

Comment: @enzolima Did you had problem with duplicate ids like I did? Honestly wondering because I do want it to work, as this would be a useful script.

Comment: I have not had this problem! I've only run the script with 1 .min_match, not multiple since I'm looking for the greediest match possible. Do you have results from your test that you can post here? Maybe I can reproduce it with my larger data set and try to find a solution.

Comment: @Salix i think i'm running into the problem that you described now. I'm going to update the main post to include it.

Comment: Try that. I can't promise there are no edge cases left (like when something is zero length), but I tried to trap most of them. I think I might have to put pencils down on this at this point. I have also cleaned up some comments here that no longer apply.

Answer (score 2):

You can order your df by first and then check if each row matches the one under it. When it does, you replace the NA values with the values of the other row.
And then you can remove duplicates.

I twweked the previous function to have the best merge while keeping IDs, and simplified it since you didn't need the extra params.

I added entries to better test.

**new function :**

```
 merge_rows <- function(df, orderCol = 0){
  if(orderCol[1]==0){ #if no column is used to sort --> replace missing values
    df <- merge_rows(df)
  } else { #else --> sort, then replace missing values
    for(L in c(T, F)){ #depending on how NAs are ordered, you get different results, so doing it both ways to assure better merging
      for(i in 1:length(orderCol)){
        df <- df[order(df[orderCol[i]], na.last=L),]
        row = 2 #counter and not for loop because size of df changes
        while(row <= nrow(df)){
          r1 = row-1
          r2 = row
          #compare the 2 rows & checks that it's a match (no conflicting data)
          is_match = sum((df[r1,-1] == df[r2,-1])==F, na.rm = T) == 0  # -1 for id col
          #if it's a match --> fill missing info of row 1 and remove row 2
          if(is_match) {
            df[r1, is.na(df[r1,])] <- df[r2, is.na(df[r1,])]
            df <- df[-r2, ]
          } 
          row = row+1
        }
      }
    }
  }
  rownames(df) <- NULL #rename your row in order
  return(df) #return new df
}

merge_rows(df, 2:3) #in my case 2:3 gave same result as 2:5, depending on your columns, you might need to adjust
```

**result:**

```
   id first      last birthyear father
1 84z  <NA> degeneres      1950   hank
2 1y9   pam degeneres      1855   <NA>
3 a12 linda      john      1991    dan
4 d33 linda      well      1991 robert
5 3n8   max      well      1915   mike
```

**df used :**

```
df <- data.frame(
    id = c("d33","d34","a11", "a12", "3n8", "15z", "ba4", "1y9", "84z", "9i5"), 
    first = c("linda","linda",NA, "linda", "max", "linda", "max", "pam", NA, "max"), 
    last = c("well","well","john", "john", "well", NA, NA, "degeneres", "degeneres", "well"), 
    birthyear = c("1991","1991","1991", "1991", "1915", "1991", NA, "1855", "1950", NA), 
    father = c(NA,"robert",NA, NA, NA, "dan", NA, NA, "hank", "mike"), 
    stringsAsFactors = T)
```

Comment: I have run your script, but I don't understand exactly what the approach is. Before I start tinkering myself, I have some questions:

Comment: 1 - in your last line you call mergeRows(df1, col, colToMatch) but "col" is not an object. Should this be "colToSort"?

Comment: 2 - related to (1), the function mergeRows expects a variable "orderCol" but this variable is never used in the function. What is it's purpose?

Comment: 3 - In your third edit you said I would not want to assume every person with the same last name and birthdate are the same person - for the purpose of my script, i want exactly this. If someone is only known as "max", i want to merge it with any other "max" and don't keep that row as a separate person.

Comment: additionally: the dataset that i'm actually working on has 1243 rows, and 11 columns (so there are more variables than in my example). When i run this script without edits, it returns 1243 rows - nothing gets matched. I think your script focuses on getting matching names, while for this set, any matching info will do.

Comment: Yes, but you should be able to change what columns you want matching or not. Here I selected columns 2 & 3, but it could be any other. The reason I did that was, let say you have 'max NA 1991 NA', 'max well 1991 dan' and 'max john NA robert', depending on how you sort the columns, with NA last or not, you might end up with 'max well 1991 dan' & 'max john NA robert' or 'max well 1991 dan' & 'max john 1991 robert'.

But I relook at my script and make sure the one I have working is the same here, cuz I did edit a couple times ^^'

Comment: re 2: I used colToMatch instead of orderCol by mistake, which might be why it doesn't reduce

Comment: You are right about that! That's actually a really nice feature to have built in, as a more generalized function. It's just that my data is about 80% filled, so these specific cases will be exceedingly rare for me. But I was surprised that a function for this did not exist already in R, so i'd be interested in working on an actual generalized function for this!

Comment: Error in paste0("df[with(df, order(", orderCol, ", na.last=T)),]") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: It runs fine if i enter mergeRows(people, colToSort, colToMatch) instead of mergeRows(people, col, colToMatch)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't get it to reduce the number of entries, though. No matching is taking place. Your script does work on the provided example in my question, but does not seem to do anything on a larger (and fuzzier) dataset.

Comment: Hi, sorry, was reviewing the function. It should now be updated properly now.

Comment: @enzolima I updated the function since you didn't need the added parameters.

Answer (score 1):

*Posting as another answer because it uses a different method.*

Inspired by Adam's function and the refining of my original function, I made one small and simplified function that gives the same result as my other one while being at least twice as fast (according to the benchmark function).

```
mergeRows <- function(df) {
  #list of rows to compare
  rows <- t(combn(1:nrow(df), 2))
  #finds first pair of rows with no conflicting dfa (no need to check that there's a match if we know there's no false match)
  is_T = which(rowSums((df[rows[, 1],-1] == df[rows[, 2],-1])==F, na.rm = T) == 0)[1]
  while(!is.na(is_T)){ 
    id <- rows[is_T,]
    df[id[1], is.na(df[id[1],])] <- df[id[2], is.na(df[id[1],])]
    df <- df[-id[2],]
    #list of rows to compare from reduce df
    rows <- t(combn(1:nrow(df), 2))
    #finds next pair of rows with no conflicting dfa
    is_T = which(rowSums((df[rows[, 1],-1] == df[rows[, 2],-1])==F, na.rm = T) == 0)[1]
  }
  rownames(df) <- NULL #optional --> renames them in order
  return(df)
}

mergeRows(df)
```